# What does this change I'm seeing in this cURL HTTP POST cookie response indicate?

Tags: cookies, curl, exchange-server, libcurl

I'm using cURL and php to query an exchange server that has Forms Based Authentication turned on. Due to FBA being on I need to collect a user's cookie authentication ids first. Yesterday everything was working: then something changed overnight and stopped working.
I noticed that the cookie ids I was getting back were different (not the ids themselves because they change with every new call. Rather, the format and other things changed).

**I use to see this:**

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

sdgh.utest.edu  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   sessionid   aeddf34c-16fe-4126-8c96-da7a33d244b9
sdgh.utest.edu  FALSE   /   TRUE    0   cadata  "0x0zHQHA3o8Vcu/DK/MWp69xkkZAJkIMts3HrOeHc4a71GN0CbqnDLiadJfKfSsseiyyxkyyUhRQ="
```

**And now I see this (notice the url on the second line and the "#HttpOnly_" in front of the 2nd id):**

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

sdgh.utest.edu  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   sessionid   11358a02-233c-4425-8a83-6b8b69b21bcd
#HttpOnly_sdgh.utest.edu    FALSE   /   TRUE    0   cadata  "0FHKgxeq7st0DW57zl5HDgZ5gp7eRDqgfG6iAyxSf4TvyJI5aZI5wmPeiEHFloGo2bvH0fpnl52c="
```

**Can anyone tell me what this sudden change indicates?**

Did something change on *my* web server?
Could it be the exchange server that I'm querying?
Did someone update cURL on me behind my back overnight?
Also, I do not have automatic updates happening on my web server.

Does anyone think this even implies that cURL was updated? I didn't update it as far as I can tell.
When/why does cURL or libcurl switch from http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html 
 to this 
 http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,here is an explanation for the #HttpOnly_ prefix: http://blog.php-security.org/archives/40-httpOnly-Cookies-in-Firefox-2.0.html

My understanding of the issue is that curl or libcurl was updated and that as a result, the server now sees it as a user-agent capable of dealing with #HttpOnly_ cookies.